# Inserting a couple of images to a UITableviewcell programmatically?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to insert a couple of images to a non custom tableview cell programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `[cell.contentView addSubView:yourImage];` You must define the `CGRect` of the `UIImageView`.